# Google Cartographer Successes on Turtlebot (Or Similar?)

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, cartographer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was just wondering if anyone has had any success yes with the likes of TurletBot (or similar robots) using Google's [Cartographer](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2016/10/introducing-cartographer.html) .

I've see TRI playing with it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cK6s7soVwws

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247040/google-cartographer-successes-on-turtlebot-(or-similar?)/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-11-03**:
There was also a roscon 2016 video https://vimeo.com/187699364, and a slide around 3:07 showing a link to http://robocup2017.org/eng/index.html, though I don't see code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [cartographer_turtlebot](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer_turtlebot) repo with a dedicated cartographer config for use with the Turtlebot, so that's probably a good place to get started.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on 2017-05-25**:
Can I use the package cartographer_turtlebot for iRobot Create2?